# How to structure email request class for different types of emails requiring different rendering params?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Currently, my notification request is like this:

```
public class EmailRequest{
  public enum EmailType{
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    ...
  }
  EmailType emailType;
  String toAddress;
  EmailRenderer renderer;
}
```

where EmailRenderer is an interface

```
public interface EmailRenderer{
  EmailMessage render()
}
```

Now, each type of email has a separate implementation of the renderer interface and each implementation contains some rendering data that has to be provided by the client. This data can be different for each implementation.

Example:

```
public class Type1EmailRenderer implements EmailRenderer{
  String param1;
  String param2;
  @Override
  EmailMessage render(){
    //rendering logic using the params
  }
}
```

But, it seems redundant to me for the user to set the email type and renderer as well. Choosing the renderer should automatically get me the emailType. How should I restructure the request to be free of this redundancy? Also, can I use any design pattern for providing the renderers to my users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll base my answer on a claim that,
putting aside programming-related questions, at the level of human logic, it looks to me strange that if I want to send an email I should know about renderers at all.

In my understanding If I have emails of different types (you've called them TYPE_1 and TYPE_2, let's give more "business" names for better clarity, like "dailyReport" or "advertisement", you'll see later why) I should just prepare a request with my data (param1, param2) and send it. I shouldn't care about renderers at all as long as the same email type assumes that the same type of renderer will be used.

So, lets say, type "advertisement" has a mandatory parameter `String topic` and optional parameter `String targetAudience` and type "dailyReport" has `Integer totalUsersCount` and optional `String mostActiveUserName`.

In this case, I propose the somewhat hybrid approach mainly based on Builder creation pattern:

```
  public class EmailRequestBuilder {

      private String toAddress;

      private EmailRequestBuilder(String to) {
          this.toAddress = to;
      }
      public static EmailRequestBuilder newEmailRequest(String to) {
          return new EmailRequestBuilder(to);
      } 

      public AdvertisementBuilder ofAdvertisementType(String topic) {
          return new AdvertisementBuilder(topic, this);
      }

      public DailyReportBuilder ofDailyReportType(Integer totalUsersCount) {
          return new DailyReportBuilder(totalUsersCount, this);
      }
      // all builders in the same package, hence package private build method,
      // concrete email type builders will call this method, I'll show at the end
      EmailRequest build(EmailType type, EmailRenderer emailRenderer) {              
          return new EmailRequest (to, type, emailRenderer);
      }
  }
  public class AdvertisementBuilder {
      private String topic;
      private EmailRequestBuilder emailRequestBuilder;
      // package private, so that only EmailRequestBuilder will be able to create it 
      AdvertisementBuilder(String topic, EmailRequestBuilder emailRequestBuilder) // mandatory parameters in constructor + reference to already gathered data {
          this.topic = topic;
          this.emailRequestBuilder = emailRequestBuilder;
      }

      // for optional parameters provide an explicit method that can be called 
      // but its not a mandatory call
      public AdvertisementBuilder withTargetAudience(String audience) {
          this.audience = audience;
          return this;
      }

      public EmailRequest buildRequest() {
          EmailRenderer renderer = new AdvertisementRenderer(topic, audience);   
          return emailRequestBuilder.build(EmailType.ADVERTISEMENT, renderer);
      }            
  }

  // A similar builder for DailyReport (I'll omit it but assume that there is a class
  class DailyReportBuilder {}
```

Now the good part about it that now you can't go wrong as a user. A typical interaction with such a construction will be:

```
  EmailRequest request =  EmailRequestBuilder.newEmailRequest("john.smith@gmail.com")
                     .ofAdvertisementType("sample topic") // its a mandatory param, you have to supply, can't go wrong
                     .withTargetAudience("target audience") // non-mandatory call
                     .buildRequest();
```

Couple of notes:

- Once you pick a type by calling `ofDailyReportType/ ofAdvertisementType` the user can't really supply parameters of different email type, because it gets "routed" to the builder that doesn't have methods for wrong parameters. An immediate implication of this is that an autocomplete will work in your IDE and people who will use this method will thank you about it ;)
- It's easy to add new email types this way, no existing code will change.
- Maybe with this approach, an `enum EmailType` will be redundant. I've preserved it in my solution but probably you'll drop it if it's not required.
- Since I sometimes restrict the visibility (package private build methods, constructors, and so forth) - it will be __the_only__way to create the request which means that no-one will create "internal" objects only because it's possible to do so. At least a malicious programmer will think twice before breaking encapsulation :)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use "factory method".

```
EmailRenderer createRenderer(EmailType type) {
  switch (type) {
  case: TYPE_1:
    return new RendererType1();
  case: TYPE_2:
    return new RendererType2();
  ...
  }
}
```

Also, you probably can introduce cashing of this objects in order not to create them every time. Maybe some lazy initialization (you create appropriate Renderer first time when you needed and after that always return that same instance).

Comment: I would get a EmailRenderer object out of this but i would still want to set the rendering data according to the subclass selected. How can I do that?
I cannot use the same renderer everytime because the rendering data would be different for each request.